# Syntax for POST using Promisify(https)

Tags: node.js, post, https, promise

I'm using the [NodeJS util.promisifiy](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function so that I can use promises and async/await with the built-in https module and not have to install any dependencies. The only thing I'm unsure about is what the syntax should be for a POST request, since you normally write the request data into the stream:

```
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    //stuff
});

req.write(data);
```

Does it work the same way if the https module has been "promisified"? As such:

```
const request = promisify(https.request);
var req = request(options);
req.write(data);
```

Or like this:

```
var response = await request(options, data);
```

I can't seem to find any information on what the syntax is for the http/https functions when they've been promisified. All of the examples I've found use the fs module.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell: No, it will not work.

All that `promisify` does is wrap a function that follows the "error-first callback" design into a promise. For this to work, the given function must:

- Accept number [0..n] parameters to configure the function
- Accept a `function` as it's last (or only) parameter

It is expected that the callback-function passed in as the last parameter is called with:

- An error-object which is either falsy (indicating success) or an Error (indicating failure)
- Any number of additional arguments that represent the result of the function.

If all these criteria are met, a "promisified function" does the following:

1. Call the original function with all the given parameters and its own callback
2. Check if the first argument to the callback is falsy

   - If so, `reject` the promise with the first argument
   - If not, `resolve` the promise with any additional arguments

---

Knowing the above, we can easily implement our own "promisified" version of the request method:

```
// untested example code!
function postData(options, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = https.request(options);
        req.on("data", (chunk) => {});
        req.on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        })
        req.on("end", (res) => {
            // check if result is satisfactory and either resolve/reject here
            if (res.isFine) {
                resolve(res);
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Response indicated failure"));
            }
        });
        // Send the data off 
        req.write(data); 
    });
}
```

This is more verbose than just calling a single function, but it simple to read and it's clear what this function does.

**Personal** word of advice: Stay away from such "utilities". If you don't understand whats happening inside your code, how can you debug it? The bit of overhead needed to create a simple wrapper like this far outweighs the "hope" that the function does it's job as you *expect* it to.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, although it's quite a bit of boilerplate.  Another option is using one of the frequently used modules that does this wrapping for you, like [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Comment: @ElliotNelson I think this is problematic. This is not complicated code, on the contrary it makes _you_ think about all the things that _could_ go wrong and handle them. If you found a working solution for yourself, there is nothing wrong with reusing it. My specific problem with the module you linked is, that it uses Bluebird (yet another dependency) where Promisses are built into NodeJS core. To me that is unnecessary.

Comment: Fair enough; I guess that definitely depends on the shop (if every nodejs project on your team already uses Bluebird, then that isn't a cost).